# Apache/IIS redirect subfolder with same domain name

Tags: iis, apache-2.4, redirect

I have 2 servers :
-1 in IIS
-1 in apache

I have a domain like example.com .
i would to make some redirection so when you enter http://example.com you are going on the IIS server
When you enter http://example.com/blog or http://example.com/CRM you are going to the apache server.

What is the best way to do it ? on which server ? I would like to keep the real name ( no subdomain or something else ).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: What you are looking for is called a Reverse Proxy. It's effectively a webserver that takes requests from the client and forwards them to a different webserver, usually on the internal network.

Both Apache and IIS are capable of doing this. Another application commonly used for this purpose is nginx. There should be plenty of documentation for your webserver of choice on how to set this up.

Comment: thanks, I willl look at that